# Javascript Alphanumeric String Comparison

Tags: javascript, string-comparison, alphanumeric

I have a list of string 'X1','X2','X3','S1','S2','S3',etc. I want to do the following comparison

```
var string = INPUT STRING;
if( string > 'X10' ){
    DO THIS
}else{
    DO THAT
}
```

In this case, if the input string is 'X8' then my code is returning X8 IS GREATER than X10. If there a way I can truly get X10 > X8?

Comment: What is your expected result for comparing `X10` and `Y8`?

Comment: I am going to compare string starting with same alphabet.

Comment: In that case, you need to do something like what @minitech suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split it into alphabetical and numeric parts. Assuming the alphabetical part is only one character,

```
var alpha = string.charAt(0);
var num = string.substring(1) | 0; // | 0 to cast to integer

if (alpha > 'X' && num > 10) {
    …
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking out for a natural sorting or comparison of alphanumeric strings, you can try using the [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method.

It outputs a -1, 0 or 1 for results which are less than, equal or greater than respectively. It has some interesting options to provide as well. For instance, to get a natural alphanumeric sort (x10 < x8), you may pass the `numeric: true` option. To also make the case insensitive while comparing the string, you may also pass `sensitivity: 'base'` option. This would compare the two strings `value` and `VALUE` as equal, ignoring the casings.

An example using both the options is below:

```
leftString.localeCompare(rightString, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'})
// With this you would get following results
// X8 < X10
// X8 === x8
```

Hope this is useful. Cheers!